# How to rewrite JS with CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, css, coffeescript

I have such code in JS:

```
$('.slider-for').find('img').each(function(){
  var imgClass = (this.width/this.height > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
  $(this).addClass(imgClass);
})
```

And need to rewrite it in Coffee. There is what I've got:

```
$('.slider-cover-photo img').each ->
  imgClass = if $(this).width / $(this).height > 1 then 'wide' else 'tall'
  $(this).addClass imgClass
```

`this` here is a correct  element. But when I try to get its width or height, its value is 0 (`$(this).width = 0`)

Comment: Why `this.width` in your JavaScript but `$(this).width` in your CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `$(this).width`and `$(this).height` in the coffeescript instead of `this.width` and `this.height`.

```
$('.slider-for').find('img').each ->
   imgClass = if this.width / this.height > 1 then 'wide' else 'tall'
   $(this).addClass imgClass
```

You can also use `@` instead of `this` in Coffeescript

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use http://js2.coffee/ that is great for converting **js to coffee or coffee to js**. This site return coffee script against your js

```
$('.slider-for').find('img').each ->
  imgClass = if @width / @height > 1 then 'wide' else 'tall'
  $(this).addClass imgClass
  return
```

N.B -> Don't always trust on auto conversion. At least try to read yourself the output.